# Retrieving images from eBay's gallery using eBay API

Tags: arrays, ebay-api

So I'm very new to developing with eBay's API (or any API) and can't seem to work out how to reference the images from the gallery in the listing template. I don't want to use the URL specifically but rather use the eBay API to bring the images in from the eBay gallery so you don’t have to upload the images twice.

From What I understand, this can be done through an array using `Item.PictureDetails.PictureURL`. But I could be wrong.

Anyone done/know how to do this? Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using PHP with XML.
So, if i understand your problem, you must call GetItem API (http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/GetItem.html) to retrieve the data for a single item.

This call return an xml where you can find picture URL.